# Copy fields from one model to another model that includes the same fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have a Model called 'templates' with fields 'a,b,c,d,e,f,g' and I have a "reports' model with unique fields but also the same fields that 'templates' has: 'blue,red,gold,green,a,b,c,d,e,f,g').

Say on the form for a new Report, there's a drop list to pick a template and the value of that list will be a template id.  So, in the create action for Reports, I create a new Report object and then find the selected template by id.

```
@report = Report.new(params[:report])
@template = find(params[:report][:template_id])
```

At this point (considering that the @report object includes all the fields the @template object does), is there a consise way of copying the values of @template into the @report object?

Thanks!
Rails 2.3.5 / Ruby 1.8.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way:

```
@report = Report.new(params[:report])
@template = find(params[:report][:template_id])
@template.attributes = @report.attributes #this copies fields from report to template
```

Comment: Ha - thanks.  I never thought about it before, but on a "create" action Rails is smart enough not to send the 'id' field with the insert statement.  Although when you do a ".save" exactly what is Rails looking at to determine it shouldn't pass the id with the insert?

Comment: Take also into consideration that the fields which are going to be copied are only the ones defined in your ```attr_accesible``` statement.